# Reports - field names in Filter tab all blanks!

Tags: civireport

In Reports, the field names on the left side in the 'Filters' tab are all blank.  I don't know when this happened but it affects all reports. 'Columns' tab is OK.  Another system I have at the same level (5.53.0) is not affected.  This is really odd! - I've cleared caches, disabled ReportPlus, cleared caches again but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think is some rogue css coming from somewhere, like `div#report-tab-set-filters td.label { display: none; }`. If you right-click and choose "inspect", are they there in the html but have some css hiding them?

Comment: or the color of the font is same as background color?

Comment: I had Bootstrap3.26 as the CiviCRM Admin theme (D7 system), when I switched it to Seven the problem went away.   Thanks both for the replies, which put me on the right track.  However, an application that was 'responsive' i.e. usable on a phone, now isn't anymore. I guess I should experiment with Bootstrap 3 settings to see if that will work for both situations or find another theme.